# Writing a compiler frontend. When should I check if a variable was declared or not?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, variable-declaration

I'm currently writing a compiler in C for my own programming language.

Now I'm working on the front-end. I've added functions recently, and now I have troubles with checking if a variable was declared or not.

Before adding functions, declaration of a variable in EBNF looked like this:

```
<Assign> ::= <VariableDeclarator>? <Lvalue> "=" <Rvalue>
```

(declaration in my language is available only with initialization).

But now, when I have functions, I have to declare all its parameters before its body.

This brings extra complexity to my lexer, which determines if a variable was declared or not.

I have a single name table for the whole program.

I know that there is an idea of having multiple name tables in a stack, but I don't know if it can help solve my problem.

I don't understand how to check if a variable in a function body was declared or not.

Comment: Why would the lexer check if a variable is declared or not? That is usually the job of the parser. If your grammar is context-free, you can delay the check as much as semantic analysis of the AST because you can parse variable names, even if you don't know whether they refer to valid symbols.

Comment: Ok, i will make parser responsible for this, thank you

Comment: I don’t understand what further‘ details or clarity’ this question could possibly need. Rather trivial, but not unclear. VTR

Comment: @user207421: As Jan Schultke notes, it is not trivial, because when you need to determine whether a name is declared or not may depend on the grammar. In C, what tokens are allowed after an identifier may depend on what type of thing the identifier refers to. In that case, you need to determine the type immediately after seeing the identifier. If the type is not encoded in the name (e.g., “all functions begin with f”), you need there to have been a declaration for it. But another language might not require that context sensitivity, or it could default all undeclared identifiers to…

Comment: … an object type. In that case, you could have a language that allows use of identifiers before they are declared, or even if they are never declared. OP has not specified the characteristics of their programming language, so it is not known when they need to have identifier declarations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is trivial that you don't do it in the lexer. The question is about whether the variable was declared or not, not about its type. The lexer doesn't know whether it's dealing with a declaration, a definition, or a use.

Comment: @user207421: No, the question is not about whether the variable was declared or not. The question is “When should I check if a variable was declared or not?” The answer to that depends on the language. There is not a universal answer for all programming languages. Also, it can be up to a lexer to look up an identifier. A language could allow the declaration of new keywords, and the lexer may be responsible for providing a keyword token versus a variable token versus an unknown-identifier token to the parser. There are multiple ways to design languages, lexers, and parsers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is a distinction without a difference. Obviously we are both talking about the same thing.